# Allocating 2D array with pointer to fixed-size array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-allocation

Is it valid in C to dynamically allocate 2d arrays this way?

```
//fixed size
int (*arr2d)[9][9]=malloc(sizeof(int[9][9]));

//variable size
int x=5,y=3;
int (*arr2d)[x][y]=malloc(sizeof(int[x][y]));

//assignment
(*arr2d)[0][1]=2;
```

EDIT:
By "valid" I mean, are there any pitfalls as opposed to:

```
int i,x=5,y=10;
int **arr2d=malloc(sizeof(int*[x]));
for(i=0;i < x;i++)
    arr2d[i]=malloc(sizeof(int[y]));

arr2d[0][0]=5;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real issue is if you request more memory than the `malloc` call can satisfy (you may have enough memory available, but not in a single, contiguous block).

To save your sanity, do something like this instead:

```
T (*arr)[cols] = malloc( sizeof *arr * rows );
```

This will allow you to index it as `arr[i][j]` instead of `(*arr)[i][j]`.